# how to use throw exception in java

Tags: java

I have problems using try-catch in method `inverse()`, after running the code I get this error:

> Exception TanpaInvers is never thrown in body of corresponding try
>   statement

The code is like this:

*class SalahIndex*

```
public class SalahIndeks extends Exception {
    public SalahIndeks(String pesan) {
        super(pesan);
    }
}
```

*class TanpaInverse*

```
public class TanpaInverse extends Exception {
    public TanpaInverse(String pesan) {
        super(pesan);
    }
}
```

*method class Matrix2x2*

```
    double determinan(){
    int a11 = 0, a12 = 0, a21 = 0, a22 = 0;

    double determinan = this.a11 * this.a22 - this.a12 * this.a21;
    return determinan;
}

Matriks2x2 inverse() throws TanpaInverse, SalahIndeks {

    Matriks2x2 A = new Matriks2x2(a11, a12, a21, a22);
    double detA = A.determinan();

    if (detA != 0){
        try{
            double a11 = this.a22/detA;
            double a12 =  -this.a12/detA; 
            double a21 =  -this.a21/detA;
            double a22 =  this.a11/detA;

        }
        catch(TanpaInverse errT){}    
        catch(SalahIndeks e){}
    }

    return new Matriks2x2(a11, a12, a21, a22);
}
private int a11, a12, a21, a22;
}
```

Comment: The error is what is says it is. `TanpaInverse` and `SalahIndeks` can never be thrown inside your try-block. The division operations you perform, will never throw these errors by themselves.

Comment: And catching exceptions only to ignore them is worse than pointless anyway.

Answer (score 3):

What the compiler is complaining about is that in your code you say by `catch` something like "when a TanpaInverse is thrown, do this", while your code will definitely not throw such an exception.

Instead, you should use throw our exceptions if sth. is going wrong with the matrix. Not knowing what Tanpa and Salah in your language mean, it's hard to say when they should be thrown, but sth. like this would seem right to me:

```
// here goes code for "if some condition is violated, throw a new SalahIndeks

if (detA != 0){

         double a11 = this.a22/detA;
         double a12 =  -this.a12/detA; 
         double a21 =  -this.a21/detA;
         double a22 =  this.a11/detA;

} else {
  throw new TanpaInverse();
}
```

THis way, any method calling your `inverse` can/must have a `try/catch` block to handle **possible** exceptions.